# What's the meaning of macroBS and microBS?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I'm reading a book and came across "... they only discovered too late; one can macroBS longer than microBS,. ."

Couldn't understand the phrase.

Comment: What was the book and context?

Comment: What does "macro" mean?  What does "micro" mean?  What does "BS" mean?

Comment: @JasonBassford Forward of the book: The Bitcoin Standard.

Comment: @Ricky - Ah, *that* BS!!

Comment: @HotLicks at first I thought the same! Just wanted to know if it means sth else :)

Comment: @Ricky - It's BS either way!

Comment: Presumably, those terms are explained in the book. It's a good guess that, in this context, *BS* stands for *Bitcoin Standard*.

Comment: It should be noted that the author may, in some instances, pun the two meanings of "BS".  Hard to tell without knowing a lot more context.

Answer (score 1):

> one can macroBS longer than microBS,. ."
> the respective verbs are **to microbullshit** and **to macrobullshit**

OED

> **bullshit**  v. transitive and intransitive, **to talk nonsense (to); = bull v.3; also, to bluff one's way through (something) by talking nonsense.**
>
> 1969   P. Roth Portnoy's Complaint 105   *Please, let us not bullshit one another about ‘love’ and its duration.*

"**micro-**" prefix

> **1.a. Forming terms in which micro- indicates small (often microscopic) or relatively small size, frequently in contrast with related terms beginning with macro- or mega-.**

Thus "on a small scale, in a detailed manner, precisely. Hence, **Macro-** on a large scale, in general, in broad terms

Thus

**to macrobullshit** = to talk nonsense (to); = bull v.3; also, to bluff one's way through (something) **in general or broad terms, or with reference to large scale effects.**

**to microbullshit** = to talk nonsense (to); = bull v.3; also, to bluff one's way through (something) **addressing the smaller aspects, thus, in a detailed way**.

Answer (score 0):

While the book is about the **B**itcoin **S**tandard the phrase tells the tail of the details beneath the marketing.

The realization that they come to is that BS refers to *Bovus Excretus* or Bull Sh*t. The idiom of BS-ing is to talk, speak at length and basically bloviate all with the end value of said excrement, that is, none at all.

I understand the meanings of these macroBS and microBS in the Bitcoin world. But here the delineation between macroBS and microBS is between talking in large, grand terms devoid of detail vs. talking in micro, smaller terms where the lack of detail is eventually, if only too late, apparent.

*"And dull surprise when payment due exceeds accounts received."*

Comment: Tells the tail?

Comment: I don’t think this answer reflects the intent of the intro to the book. The intro is by Nassim Taleb, who wrote the book about the black swan theory; he is favorable to the bitcoin concept.

Comment: In my judgement there is a lot of BS associated with Bitcoin.

Comment: Even though Mr. Taleb believes in the concept he is telling us that he ran out of room in his discussions. I am sure he had better luck some time later.

Comment: I'm sorry, in contrast BTC the BS has actually real value as fertilizer at least. @HotLicks, suppose it is very much implied that the BS is something one has to shovel through to get to the real value of distributed trusts.

Comment: @vectory - BS is something you don't want in your wallet.